# Mysql select, if input arguments are same dont return any rows

Tags: mysql, input, arguments

I have a bit of an odd mysql query I need to run.

I am passing two arguments to a WHERE clause, $source and $destination (via php). I want mysql to simply return nothing if $source and destination are the same number. Otherwise do the lookup in the DB and pull the record.

Query:

```
SELECT count(id) AS count
FROM approval
WHERE source=1 AND destination=2 AND approved!=0
```

Now this will return all rows where source is one and destination is two.

BUT! I want it it to return nothing if source and destination are the same number.
Some rows in certain cases may contain the same number, but that happens in a different potion of the code, in this specific select I want it only to perform the search if source and destination are different. I looked at comparison operators but those all seem to be checking the argument against a value in the column, rather than an argument against an argument.

Comment: It's not clear from your question which parts of your query are being supplied by PHP. Can't you  just add an extra term to your where clause: `and (source != destination)`

Comment: By "return nothing", do you mean "return no rows"?  Or does this mean something else to you?

Comment: `select count()` will always return 1 row, even if the value is zero.

Comment: @HoboSapiens . . . Not if you have a `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a simple matter of including:

```
and source <> destination
```

in the query. This will exclude rows where the columns are the same which, because of the other clauses, means the arguments you've provided are the same as well.

This will probably still go *out* to the database but it's guaranteed to return a count of zero (assuming no NULLs of course - if you want to handle those, you'll need extra clauses with `IS [NOT] NULL`). If you don't even want to go out to the database if your two arguments are the same, the time to do that is in your PHP code by comparing the *arguments* beforehand.

By way of example, the following DDL:

```
create table xyzzy (a int, b int);
insert into xyzzy (a,b) values (1,1);
```

creates a table with one row. When you execute the queries:

```
SELECT count(a) AS x FROM xyzzy WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1;
SELECT count(a) AS x FROM xyzzy WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1 and a <> b;
```

you'll get the rows `1` (equivalent to what you currently have) and `0` (equivalent to the change I've proposed).

If you *really* want to use the parameters instead of the columns, that will work as well:

```
SELECT count(a) AS x FROM xyzzy WHERE a = 1 AND b = 1 and 1 <> 1;
```

This also returns a count of zero and is equivalent to just tacking:

```
and $source <> $destination
```

onto your query. If the two numbers are identical, this will boil down to `and false` which will result in a count of zero.

So will either of:

```
and source <> $destination
and $source <> destination
```

for that matter.

Comment: Not really.  That will result in a count of 0, as opposed to no rows being returned.

Comment: @Gordon, that depends on the intent of the OP, which is unclear. They state it returns _rows_ but there is no way for `count` to return more than one row without a grouping clause. I read it as simply returning no rows from the "underquery" resulting in a count of zero when aggregating.

Comment: Trying to find a way to explain this. Essentially I want to result in 'count' being 0. I tried $source!=$destination (using both != and <> methods). I didnt know about having, but that didnt seem to do anything either it still set count as 1.

Comment: I am trying to essentially do a check, because I use this query to return to php a list of fake tables (via the AS command) with either 0 or 1. Each 0 or 1 is the result of various conditions my app checks for. One thing this count will be used for is to ensure that you dont add a record where the source and destination are true (if it returns 1, php can check that and skip a section or code or return a warning knowing the user is trying to insert a record I dont want him to because it already exists. If its 0 just go ahead and process the next part of the code because it wasnt done yet).

Comment: @Mark, the `having` won't give you a count of zero, it will give you a recordset with no rows. I suggest you re-read the `and` clause in my answer, that `source` and `destination` are the _column_ names, not the PHP variables - in other words, leave off the `$`. I'll clarify in the answer.

Comment: The thing is I need to make sure that the php variable (after php replaces the variable with a number and sends it to sql) doesnt equal the same number. I would do this in php if I could but I need to do the comparison check in the sql for various reasons.

So I need this essentially:
SELECT count(id) AS count FROM approvals WHERE source=2 AND destination=2 AND approved!=0 AND 1!=2

It needs to make sure 1 doesnt equal 2

Comment: I think I messed up somewhere else in the statement, trying it again using simple tables seems to result in the count of 0 when the two variables are the same. I appreciate the feedback and think I just messed up somewhere

Comment: Mark, no problems. In fact, _either_ of the `source <> destination`, `$source <> $destination`, `source <> $destination` and `$source <> destination` will actually give you what you want.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I dont know where I was going wrong but I rewrote the entire parent statement and paid attention to the conditions and its working exactly as claimed. I am still glad I asked because its good to know it intentionally works that way and not a bad hack job or something that "happens" to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query does what you want

```
SELECT count(id) AS count
FROM approvals
WHERE source = $source AND destination = $destination AND approved <> 0
HAVING $source <> $destination;
```

Comment: It doesnt work.... 

I think this query does what you want

SELECT count(id) AS count
FROM approvals
WHERE source = 2 AND destination = 2 AND approved <> 0
HAVING 2 <> 2;
If a row exists where source and destination are 2, it still returns a count of 1, even though we trying specifying having 2<>2. It seems to ignore that?

Comment: Mark, this _does_ work as Gordon has it, he's using the PHP parameters to dictate whether the count is returned or no row is returned. I think that's not what you want (you seem to be asking for a single row with a count of zero rather than no row at all) but, if I'm mistaken, then this will do it.

Comment: I think I messed up somewhere else in the statement, trying it again using simple tables seems to result in the count of 0 when the two variables are the same. I appreciate the feedback and think I just messed up somewhere